# How to console log when offsetLeft reach a number of pixels

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple game: drag en element far enough (200px) The console logs fine, when I drag the element 200px the console reads 200px, but I still get the wrong message.(not there yet)..

```
function far_enough() {
    console.log('You have moved the box ' + el.offsetLeft + 'pixels');

    if(el.offsetleft == 200){
        console.log('200px great!');
    } else {
        console.log('not there yet!');
    }

}

}
```

Comment: `el.offsetLeft` could be different on this two different times

Comment: Try giving a bit of offset from both sides, it's very difficult to get it to exactly 200px, so maybe something like `if(el.offsetLeft >= 180 && el.offsetLeft <= 220){ console.log('200px great!');}`

Comment: ...the offset from both sides worked, maybe if it's just 0.01px off it's wrong. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
function far_enough()
  {
  let leftOffset = el.offsetLeft;

  console.log('You have moved the box ' + leftOffset + 'pixels');

  if (leftOffset == 200)
    {
    console.log('200px great!');
    } 
  else
    {
    console.log('not there yet!');
    }
  }
```

Comment: ...by setting let leftoffset = el.offsetLeft, you create a delay right? Circumventing that the offsetLeft might be different on two times, right?

Comment: your code lets assume that the `el` element can continue to evolve while the function is running, so if you want to test its value at a time T, you must temporarily keep this reference value to test it at different places in your function

Comment: el.offsetLeft can not change in the middle of a synchronous function. this answer is misleading

Comment: @Max I second this.

Comment: @Max @Richard, I didn't say that, console.log don't show the `el.offsetLeft` value on exact function moment

Comment: @MisterJojo you did say that in your comment to this answer. Besides, console.log always shows exact value of primitives at the moment it's called, which is the case here

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, `element.offsetLeft` can return a decimal value. This means that it may return `200.01px` instead of `200px` exactly. This is what's causing your code to not work. A simple work-around is simply to use `Math.round(element.offsetLeft)` to return an integer value. However, even when using this, there's a chance that the `offsetLeft` does not return `200px` exactly, especially when you drag the element too fast (the browser does not repaint for each pixel moved). Another solution is to use a range like from `200px` to `250px`.

I suppose that you're using `position: absolute` and manipulating `left` CSS property to cause the element to be draggable. However, moving elements with  `transform` **is better** than using `position`. I highly suggest reading this [article on why](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

As you're moving your element using `transform` now, the `offsetLeft` value of the element never changes. Therefore, you can alternatively get the rendered box position using `getBoundingClientRect()`. Here's an example using a `getBoundingClientRect()`, which returns a `left` value relative to the viewport.

```js
const draggable = document.querySelector('#draggable')

function farEnough() {
  const box = draggable.getBoundingClientRect()
  // Get center of box; move center of box by 200px to return true
  let center = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2
  if (center >= 200 && center <= 300) return true
  else return false
}

let dragging = false
let dragStartX = null
let dragStartY = null
let draggableMovedX = null
let draggableMovedY = null

function dragHandler(e) {
  dragging = true
  dragStartX = e.clientX
  dragStartY = e.clientY
}

function moveHandler(e) {
  if (dragging) {
    let moveX = e.clientX - dragStartX + draggableMovedX
    let moveY = e.clientY - dragStartY + draggableMovedY
    draggable.style.transform = `translate(${moveX}px, ${moveY}px)`

    if (farEnough()) {
      draggable.removeEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler)
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler)
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', leaveHandler)
      dragging = false
      dragStartX = null
      dragStartY = null
      // 175px so that the center of the box is exactly at 200px from the left
      draggable.style.transform = `translate(175px, ${moveY}px)`
      console.log('You did it! You moved it 200px to the right!')
    }
  }
}

function leaveHandler(e) {
  dragging = false
  dragStartX = null
  dragStartY = null
  const box = draggable.getBoundingClientRect()
  draggableMovedX = box.left
  draggableMovedY = box.top
}

draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler)
window.addEventListener('mouseup', leaveHandler)
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #121212;
  cursor: grab;
}

#draggable:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable"></div>
<div id="line"></div>
```